# The jQuery AJAX and PHP not fetching data values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to fetch the values of the data variable passed with jQuery AJAX to a php page. How to solve it?

Below is the HTML page code:

```
<input id="name" placeholder="Enter your name." />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<div id="message"></div>
```

On the button click this jQuery AJAX calls a php page:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "jquery-ajax-hello.php",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: '{"name":"' + $("#name").val() + '"}',
     success: function (result, status, xhr) {
         $("#message").html(result);
     },
     error: function (xhr, status, error) {
         $("#message").html("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)
     }
 });
```

The PHP Page code is:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo "Hello ".$name.", How are you ?"; 
?>
```

In the php page I am not able to fetch the data varaible 'name' value?

Please help?

Comment: What is the error in console??

Comment: Undefined index: name in E:\xampp\htdocs\demo\jquery-ajax-hello.php on line 2
Hello , How are you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `data` should be an object, what you're passing is a string, so it should be

```
data: {
    name: $("#name").val()
},
```

Comment: try removing `contentType`, it should really just pass as a www/encode thing.

Comment: thanks, i removed contentType and that solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: jQuery's ajax doesn't actually pass it as a json object (as one might infer), it passes it as a query string. See more on their website.

Answer (score 1):

### JQuery Ajax

> Form data

```
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name." />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<div id="message"></div>
```

> Jquery section

```
$(function() {
$("#submit").click(function() {
  var name = $('#name').val();
 $.ajax({
  url : 'success.php',
  method: 'POST',
  data : {name:name},
  success : function(res) {
     $('#message').append(res);
   }
});
});
});
```

> success.php

```
<?php 
 $name =  $_POST['name'];
 echo "Hello Mr ".$name ;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

change **data** property to

```
 data: {name: $("#name").val() }
```

and it would work fine

Answer (score 0):

change data to:

```
data: { name: $("#name").val() }
```

because `data` must be an object having `key : value` pair in it

In your case:

```
data: '{"name":"' + $("#name").val() + '"}'
```

`{}` is wrapped with single quotes. Remove them.

Comment: the php page is not able to fetch the "name" value, that's the problem?

Comment: In that case data : name do no have the value in it